# Microprofile health on two applications

Tags: java, microprofile

I have two applications on which I would like to have the health endpoints from microprofile.
When I try and run these in parallel the second will fail. Is there a way to change the port.

I have tried adding the flag `Dmicroprofile.http.port=` when running the `jar` as found on the microprofile Google group but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I could not find a direct answer I did implement a solution.
Adding the flag Dswarm.port.offset did work for my current setup dding an ofsett of 100 to all my used ports in that jar.